# Connecting Android app to MySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

Can somebody help me with question related with MySQL database using?

Yesterday i was making app for getting some text data and sending them to database located on remote server!

I was making POST request to database and sent few text fields to one table in database.
So MY QUESTION IS:

"Can I use MySQL directly (not though POST method )? and how to use it ?"
(will be so glad to see url to solutions or examples)

P.S. when i was sending data to server i have some errors in database fields when sending russian characters (what type of encoding sending from my app to server????)

Comment: You should not place your database with your mobile application, rather then that you should make remote request for dbIO.

Comment: it's best to use `utf-8` but it's not secure at all to allow "anyone" to connect to your database. you should consider creating an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

Comment: Take a look at this example, It will help you to connect mysql database [Example 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) [Example 2](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-login-activity-with-mysql.html)